# How would I solve this probability problem?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

[image]
I'm trying to solve this problem for couple of days but can't seem to figure it out. Can someone let me know if I'm even going in the right direction? Thanks in advance

This what I have so far

```
|L ∩ T| U A ≤ 100
|L ∩ T| + |A| - |L ∩ T ∩ A| ≤ 100
115 - |L ∩ T ∩ A| ≤ 100
- |L ∩ T ∩ A| ≤ -15
|L ∩ T ∩ A| ≥ 15
```

Comment: You have that exactly correct!  Yes, the minimum is $15$, and your approach is spot on!

Comment: Cool. Just making sure

Comment: Next time please take the time to enter critical parts of your question as text instead of posting an image. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to people using screen readers, nor do they show up in summaries of the question. I find it hard to imagine that it would’ve taken more work to type in those few sentences as it was to take a photo or screen shot, crop it, upload it and link it to the question.

Comment: Also, please use MathJax to format your mathematical expressions. You can find a quick reference and tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).